# How to assign an alternating row number based on a table primary key?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql

I have a table with data named Product

```
ProductID  ProductName
1            ABC
2            PQR
3            XYZ
4            HJK
5            LKJ
6            MNB
...          ....
```

with many more product in it. What I want is result like this on Select query:

```
RowNo ProductID ProductName
1      1           ABC
1      2           PQR
2      3           XYZ
2      4           HJK
1      5           LKJ
1      6           MNB
2      7           klj
2      8           hjg
```

then 1,1, 2,2 1,1 for the number of records in the table. Is it possible, and if so how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for your sample data which assumes ProductID is contiguous:

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN ProductID % 4 = 0 OR (ProductID+1) % 4 = 0 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END,
   ProductID,
   ProductName
FROM
   Product
```

Now, guessing that you mean in resultset which may have gaps in ProductID

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN ContiguousProductID % 4 = 0 OR (ContiguousProductID+1) % 4 = 0 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END,
   --ContiguousProductID,
   --CASE WHEN ProductID % 4 = 0 OR (ProductID+1) % 4 = 0 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END,
   ProductID,
   ProductName
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ProductID) AS ContiguousProductID,
        ProductName, ProductID
    FROM 
        dbo.Product
    ) P2
```

Comment: Thanks @gbn i got result on some editing on the same query actualy i want to apply 1 to the first two rows then 2 to the second two irrespective of the data.